# webbrowser-control missing content on load

Tags: c#, .net, events, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser-Control that is displaying Markdown with MarkDig.
I'm loading the markdown content from my DB, and load it into the webbrowser-controller.
At the same time, I have a textbox next to it, with the same content as the webbrowser-controller, there is an event on the textbox with TextChanged, so when the content in the textbox is changed, it inserts the new text into the webbrowser-controller, and displays it as markdown.

My problem is, when the application loads and the webbrowser-controller is getting the content, it is not displayed in the webbrowser. But the content is displayed in the textbox. The content in the webbrowser is not displayed before I change something in the textbox.

Loaded as normal:
[image]

This is when I have added a space after the text "An h1 header" in the top
[image]

This is my TextChanged event, which loads the text in the textbox into the webbrowser. If I out comment this line, it works and loads fine.

```
private void textBox_KB_markdown_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wbMarkDown.DocumentText = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(textBox_KB_markdown.Text);
        }
```

And this is how I load the content from my DB, into the webbrowser-controller and the textbox.

```
private void GetKBContent()
        {
            OpenConection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Knowlagebase WHERE id = 1", conn);
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email_);
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password_);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string db_markdown = rdr["Markdown"].ToString();
                    string DecryptedKB_markdown = DecryptKBContent(db_markdown);

                    textBox_KB_markdown.Text = DecryptedKB_markdown;

                    string html_Markdown = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(DecryptedKB_markdown);
                    wbMarkDown.DocumentText = html_Markdown;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Content was not found", "Information");
            }

            CloseConection();
        }
```

So my question is, how can this be fixed, so the webbrowser-controller is displaying the content when loaded, and not having to edit first? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by changing the `TextChanged` to `KeyUp` instead

```
private void textBox_KB_markdown_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            wbMarkDown.DocumentText = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(textBox_KB_markdown.Text);
        }
```